# System.Reactive Observable of string combine items into single item as new Observable

Tags: c#, observable, system.reactive

I have an observable whose items emit a string value that is only a portion of the entire message that I want to publically offer as an observable.

If items come in like this:

- `"This is "`
- `"only part of"`
- `" the message."`

I want to offer a public observable whose items are emitted like:

- `"This is only part of the message."`

And I know when the message parts are a full message by the period at the end.

I have been trying to get the `Buffer` operator to work because that seems to be the right operator for my scenario, but I don't know how to tell the buffer what the closing condition is or if that's even possible.

Comment: Do I understand correctly. You want to know when you bulk data stream ended? I.e. you have a, b, c events which considered to be abc then you have h,j,k, then you discard previous and carry on with hjk?

Comment: I don't want to know when any streams end or complete.  I want to be able to chunk up or buffer the original stream so that you get the full messages as items in the stream as opposed to the pieces of the messages that the client will have to piece together themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Buffer` is the best way to do this:

```
var source = new Subject<string>();

var result = source.Publish(_source => _source
        .Buffer(_source.Where(s => s.EndsWith(".")))
    )
    .Select(l => l.Aggregate ((x, y) => x + y));

result.Subscribe(s => Console.WriteLine(s));

source.OnNext("This is ");
source.OnNext("only part of");
source.OnNext(" the message.");
source.OnNext("Not. A. Full. Message ");
source.OnNext("but end of stream anyway");
source.OnCompleted();
```

`Buffer` takes a parameter that specifies where the groups splits should happen, which we specify with the where clause. `Buffer` aggregates the messages into a list, which we then aggregate with Linq's Aggregate.

---

**EDIT**:

`Publish` avoids re-subscription. If you were to remove `Publish`, the solution would look like this, and would work:

```
var result2 = source.Buffer(
        source.Where(s => s.EndsWith("."))
    )
    .Select(l => l.Aggregate((x, y) => x + y));
```

However, `result2` would be subscribed twice to `source`, which can be a source of bugs, particularly if `source` isn't a well implemented or behaved observable. Therefore, when you subscribe twice to an observable, it's best to use `Publish`, which essentially 'forwards' the messages from the one subscription on to multiple subscriptions.

Comment: As I try this, could you explain what the purpose of `Publish` is in your answer?

Comment: awesome thanks!  That makes sense.  That sounds similar to `switchMap` operator in RxJS.  I have tests wrapped around this right now, so I try this approach out and see if the tests are still green and make sure I understand it.  Thanks again!

Comment: RxJS `switchMap` is closer to RX.NET's `SelectMany`.

Comment: That may be, I was just thinking in terms of how `switchMap` switches your subscription to the new observable.  Bad comparison ;-)

Comment: This was it.  Thank you so much!